# BumpGasUntilSafe FindTxByAttempt: record not found - Chainlink node on Ropsten

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I have successfully deployed a chainlink node from the [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node). I am currently testing sending requests to my chainlink node on Ropsten. All was fine until I started received the following error on every job: `BumpGasUntilSafe FindTxByAttempt: record not found`.  What is usually the cause of this error? And what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is fixed by adding a gas updater by running:

```
docker pull thodges/cl-gas-updater:latest
```

Then run:

```
docker run --name gas-updater -d --restart unless-stopped -it -e CL_URL=http://172.17.0.1:6688 -e CL_EMAIL=<EMAIL_HERE> -e CL_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD_HERE> -e MAX_GAS_PRICE=500000000000 -e FALLBACK_GAS_PRICE=50000000000 -e ADD_GAS_PRICE=1000000000 thodges/cl-gas-updater
```

But enter your email and password to your node in the command where is says `-e CL_EMAIL=<EMAIL_HERE> -e CL_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD_HERE>`.

Or if you're using a newer version of the node (v0.8.4?) you can just add the following environment vars to your `.env` file:

```
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
GAS_UPDATER_TRANSACTION_PERCENTILE=
ETH_GAS_BUMP_THRESHOLD=
ETH_GAS_BUMP_WEI=
```

And add whatever numbers you feel comfortable to your node for updating gas.

---

## Context

That error happens if you successfully submitted the transaction to the ETH node, the ETH node accepts the transaction, but it never broadcasts it.

This can happen:

1. With a faulty `ETH_URL` - I've seen some issues with specific ETH node service providers.
2. You are simply not sending enough gas with each transaction due to gas fluctuations of the ETH network.

Most likely it is case #2. In this event, you can either:

1. Run a gas updater
2. Manually update the gas variables and restart (not recommended)

A gas updater is just a docker job that updates your gas to the best "safe" price, based on how clogged up the network is. At this time, there is a custom gas updater you can run, however there appear to be plans to make this part of the regular Chainlink node software in the future.

To run a gas updater see the first part of this answer.

This will add a gas updating container to your node.

In the event that the issue is #1, (if the gas updater doesn't work) you may want to change ETH node providers. Try fiews.io, infura.io, or quiknode.io, or run your own ETH node.